# What naming convention can be used to differentiate property and method?

Tags: python, mocking

In my project, I have many methods and properties with similar name patterns like "is_*", "has_*", etc.

I have to remember to check every time to see if names like `obj.is_ready` is a method or a property, but at times I may be too lazy to do the checking.

Unit tests can help me avoid many such errors, for example, if I try to call `obj.is_ready()` when it's actually a property, the test would fail.

But not all errors can be caught this way, especially when mock objects are involved, for example, I may have a class X:

```
class X(object):
    @property
    def is_ready(self):
        return True
```

and I mock instance of X this way:

```
x = Mock(spec=X)
x.is_ready.return_value = False
x.is_ready()
```

This works fine, because mock object with `spec` specified can only check if an attribute name is valid, it can't help you with checking if a property is misused as a method.

So I'm thinking maybe I should use a naming convention to differentiate method and property.

Comment: Use verbs or verbal phrases for methods -- they're actions, after all -- and straight nouns for properties. Don't name properties `is_ready` even if they're dynamically calculated; that's downright confusing.

Comment: @jwilner I agree with you that nouns should be used, but when it come to boolean properties, you don't naturally have a noun to use. What do you suggest as a replacement for `is_ready`?

Comment: I suppose I was too limiting for properties -- I'd just use an adjective there: `obj.ready`. But I also think `is_ready` makes sense as a method -- `@property` is often abused and can conceal behavior that is time consuming or not idempotent. There are many calculations you want your object's API to be explicit about.

Comment: @jwilner Can't agree with you more. If the calculation is time consuming I would not make it a property. When a property is used, you are encouraging users of your class to write `obj.property` here and there. On the other hand, if it's a method, users would just cache the result in a variable.

Comment: So maybe we should use methods by default, and only use properties when it's necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Please visit - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Preferences I use for my projects

1. **Class names** - Capwords - e.g. StoreManaget
2. **Method names** - Uppercase separated by underscores - e.g. - Get_Store_Item
3. **Property names** - lowercase with words separated by underscores - e.g. - store_location
4. **Global property names** - lowercase with words separated by underscores (prefixed by g_) - e.g. - g_store_id
5. **Constant Name** - UPPERCASE - e.g. TOTAL

Conventions might vary from person-to-person but these naming conventions helps me to not to get into the situations where I need to spend time in identifying whether the property is Method/Varible/Constant/Global variable.

Comment: Idea is too avoid same naming conventions for the Class + Mothods + Variables etc. So we will need to borrow certain best practices from other languages as well. Above listed 5 practices are the ones that I follow for my projects. You may have your own which would differentiate from mine but underline idea is too help ourself to identify the Class + Methods + Variables by just their names than digging in depth.

Comment: **I know this is something not recommended by Python's own naming conventions - but we have the flexibility to decide our own naming conventions as long as that makes sense to us. For any kind of community contributions which will be used by masses - I strongly recommend to use Python's naming conventions only.**